# C# file extension to font-awesome class

Tags: c#

I want to show an icon based on the extension of the file.

filename.xls would become <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o "></i>

In a class I would call a method to extract the extension (e.g. `.xls`) and the method would provide me with the full name (e.g. `excel`) which can be set between fa-file- and -o. I have not found anything that can help get the job done. Best I could find is a jQuery function:

```
function GetAttachmentClass(extension) {
    var classes = new Array ('avi','bmp','css','doc','gif','htm','jpg','js','mov','mp3','mp4','mpg','pdf','php','png','ppt','rar','txt','xls','xml','zip');

    if (jQuery.inArray(extension, classes) < 0) {
        return 'unknown';
    }
    else {
        return extension;
    }
}
```

but this is not what I need. I need it to be in C# in the method so I can reuse this function whenever I do something similar.

My method so far:

```
private void GetAttachmentClass(string extension)
{
    string[] classes = new string[] {"avi", "bmp", "css", "doc", "gif", "htm", "jpg", "js", "mov", "mp3", "mp4", "mpg", "pdf", "php", "png", "ppt", "rar", "txt", "xls", "xml", "zip" };
    if (classes.Contains(extension))
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: store the extensions to the class name in a dictionary.

Comment: so you want to pass in the extension and get a custom icon out? or do you want the method to return something like 'html page' when you pass in .htm?

Answer (score 1):

Am not getting clearly what you are trying to do but here is a way to check the extension you have retrieved.

```
        using System.IO;

    private static void DisplayIcon(string extension)
    {
        string extensionArray = { "avi", "bmp", "css", "doc", "gif", "htm", "jpg", "js", "mov", "mp3", "mp4", "mpg", "pdf", "php", "png", "ppt", "rar", "txt", "xls", "xml", "zip" };

        var ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension("");

        for (int i = 0; i < extensionArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (extensionArray[i].Equals(extension))
            {
                // Appropriately return extension here
            }
        }
    }
```

And you can call the method like this

```
  DisplayIcon(Path.GetExtension(@"C:\myFile.xlsx"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your method to do what the jQuery method does, this will work:

```
private string GetAttachmentClass(string extension)
    {
        string[] classes = new string[] {"avi", "bmp", "css", "doc", "gif", "htm", "jpg", "js", "mov", "mp3", "mp4", "mpg", "pdf", "php", "png", "ppt", "rar", "txt", "xls", "xml", "zip" };
        if (classes.Contains(extension))
        {
            return extension;
        }

        return "unknown";
    }
```

This will return the extension, if it exists in the array, or 'unknown' if it doesn't.

If you want to map the extension to a name, you can set up a dictionary containing the extension and the name you want to return:

```
private string GetAttachmentClass(String extension)
{
    Dictionary<string,string> extensionTypes = new Dictionary<string,string>
    {
        {"htm", "HTML Page"},
        {"xls", "Excel"}
    };

    if(extensionTypes.ContainsKey(extension))
    {
        return extensionTypes[extension];
    }
    return "unknown";
}
```

This will return the value, or 'unknown' if the extension doesn't exist in the dictionary: eg. xls returns Excel.

You can set the value to be whatever you need.

Answer (score -1):

If you want extract icon for file you can use something like this:

```
var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"d:\1.png");
```

[This is MSDN article for this method.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon(v=vs.110).aspx)